# Switch button perform hide splash screen

Tags: android, android-studio, splash-screen, android-sharedpreferences, android-switch

I'm using `Switch button` (if switch button on its disable `splash` else working normal) for Disable `splash` screen. But I can't doing it. I'm try `android-activity-alias` but I'm not get any success. Please help me. (Also I'm using `Android-Studio 2.3.0`). Here is my code for

> This is my Switch Button layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/bg">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/switchButtonSplash"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="fill"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

[My Switch Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZ1AL.png)

> This is my Switch Button programming

```
package ahmer.afzal.myproject;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Switch;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Switch toggle = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
    toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            if (isChecked)
            {
                startActivity(new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
            else
                {
                    startActivity(new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, SplashActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
        }
    });
    setContentView(R.layout.setting_app_bar_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null)
    {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home)
    {
        finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

> Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="ahmer.afzal.myproject"
android:versionCode="550"
android:versionName="19.00">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS"/>

<application
    android:exported="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: What you want to do? If switch is enabled, you wanna show splash or not?

Comment: @Mr.Rabbit `Splash screen` already shown by default, I wanna if my switch button on `Splash screen` will get off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I created new **LauncherActivity** and removed previously created **SettingsActivity**

> LauncherActivity

```
package="ahmer.afzal.myproject"

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class LauncherActivity extends Activity
{
    public static String TRANSPARENT = "transparent";
    private SharedPreferences sharedPref;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(!sharedPref.getBoolean(TRANSPARENT, false))
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(LauncherActivity.this, SplashActivity.class));
        }
        else
            {
                startActivity(new Intent(LauncherActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
            finish();
    }
}
```

> Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="ahmer.afzal.myproject"
android:versionCode="550"
android:versionName="19.00">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS"/>

<application
    android:exported="true"
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".LauncherActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't take decision on the basis of what the status of switch button when the app last opened because switch button will not retain its state, you have to save it somewhere when user changes it.

In that case what you can do is save the status of your switch button in `sharedPreferences` and in `onCreate()` of your launcher activity check that status and take decision accordingly. But in this case also if your launcher activity is Splash then it will be shown at least once for a fraction of a second until you make those checks.

P.S: You can't change the launcher activity which is declared inside your manifest.

Comment: can you share with me some peace of hint code that will help me. If you can I'll be thankful to you.

Comment: Thank you! @Mr. Rabbit I do it.

Comment: @AhmerAfzal welcome! let me know if you need more help! Please accept the answer if helped.